# В laravel не срабатывает выборка по id

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

Есть страница Search (1) кликаю на выбранный элемент и перехожу  на страницу propertyprofile (2). У меня выдает такую ошибку при переходе:

```
Undefined index: imagePath(View: /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/resources/views/sh/propertyprofile.blade.php)
```

файл routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/search', [
   'uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch',
   'as' => 'sh.search'
]);

Route::get('/search/propertyprofile', [
   'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
   'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);
```

Файлы SearchController и PropertyProfileController:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function getSearch() {
$properties = Property::all();
return view('sh.search', ['properties' => $properties]);
}    }

class PropertyProfileController extends Controller
{
public function getPropertyProfile() {
$properties = Property::all();
return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}    }
```

модель Property :

```
class Property extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['imagePath', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'id'];
}
```

search.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@foreach($properties->chunk(4) as $propertyChunk)
  <div class="row">
    @foreach($propertyChunk as $property)
        <div class="col-md-3">                    
           <img src="{{ $property->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">                     
           <h3>{{ $property->title }}</h3>
           <a href="{{ route('sh.search.propertyprofile') }}">Property Profile</a>
       </div>                
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

файл propertyprofile.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   <img src="{{ $properties['imagePath'] }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
   <h3>{{ $properties['title'] }}</h3>
<!-- <p> Hello world! </p> -->
@endsection
```

А когда в propertyprofile.blade.php в @section  пишешь просто Hello world, тогда переходит без проблем... Помогите разобраться,
ведь я же в двух вьюхах одинаково подтягиваю значеня из массива.... ЧТО у меня не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('/search/propertyprofile/{item_id}', [
'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);

class PropertyProfileController extends Controller
{
public function getPropertyProfile($item_id,Request $request) {
   $properties = Property::where('item_id', $item_id) ->first();
   return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}
}
```

Вот разобрался, Asets, Вы верно натолкнули меня в нужном направлении, но там как оказалось нужно было еще добавить метод ->first()!!!

Answer (score 1):

getPropertyProfile откуда знает что вы именно на этот книгу нажали? У вас одинаковый getSearch() и getPropertyProfile() что вы этом хотите добиться?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

Примерно так

```
Route::get('/search/propertyprofile/{item_id}', [
   'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
   'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);

class PropertyProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function getPropertyProfile($item_id,Request $request) {
       $properties = Property::where('item_id', $item_id);
       return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
    }
}
```

В view просо сделайте  $properties->imagePath итп

Comment: Asets, спасибо огромное, но все равно выдает ошибку 500: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$imagePath (View: /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/resources/views/sh/propertyprofile.blade.php)